# Laravel model:all, use results (collection) in the same function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am retrieving events from DirtyEvent model and I want to create an Ical using the values from the results however it says that the values do not exist in currect collection:

```
public function handle()
{
    $event = DirtyEvent::all()
            ->pluck('startdate')
            ->pluck('endate');
    dd($event);
    $vCalendar = new \Eluceo\iCal\Component\Calendar('http://localhost/test');
    $vEvent = new \Eluceo\iCal\Component\Event();
    $vEvent ->setDtStart(new \DateTime($event->startdate))
            ->setDtEnd(new \DateTime($event->endate));
    $vCalendar->addComponent($vEvent);
    dd($vCalendar);
}
```

Comment: what is the output in `dd($event)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DirtyEvent::all()
    ->pluck('startdate')
    ->pluck('endate');
```

What you're doing here is

1. Get all events
2. Pluck the `startdate` from the collection of those events
3. Try to pluck the `enddate` from the collection of plucked startdates

Instead, you should do e.g.

```
DirtyEvent::pluck('startdate', 'enddate')->all();
```

to get an array of dates, which you can then use to populate your data.

Comment: when I do foreach ($event as $events) it only keeps the endate value and $event gives me 'startdate' => 'endate', another thing is I have 15 fields in the database, do I have to do pluck for all of them or there is another way?

Comment: Yes, that's how pluck works. If you want them as an array, use `->select('startdate', 'enddate')->get()`.